# Apache-Camel : OnCompletion and OnException query

Tags: apache-camel

In my project I want to apply separate OnCompletion and OnException processor on each newly created route.

Suppose I have to create 3 routes. For each route I am preparing a separate RouteBuilder class and doing configuration like below -

```
onException(Throwable.class).handled(true).process(new ExceptionHandlingProcessor(RouteId)).maximumRedeliveries(2)
        .redeliveryDelay(1000).retriesExhaustedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.ERROR)
        .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN);

 onCompletion().process(new OnCompletionProcessor(RouteId)) ;

        from("sftp:Configuration").routeId("test")
        .choice()
            .when(body().isEqualTo(null))
                .process(new AgeCalculatingProcessor("test"))
            .otherwise()
                .to("file:configuration").log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.")
                ;
```

My question is ....are the OnException and OnCompletion working on the route that is being created on the same Route Builder class (as I am creating only one route in each RouteBuilder class) or these will be applied to context level and will work on all the routes?

Actually I want to apply Onexception and OnCompletion on Route level, but I am getting exception (like - try moving OnException to the top of route), if I apply the OnException on each endPoint, like below -

from(sftp:conf).OnException(Throwable.class).restExceptionconf
.to(file:conf).OnException(Throwable.class).restExceptionConf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RouteBuilder level onException**: If you define onException handler like this

```java
onException(...).log("This is RouteBuilder level exception handling.");

configure() {
    from(...).to(...);
}
```

it will handler exceptions from all routes within the same RouteBuilder.

**Route level onException**: If you define onException handler like this

```java
configure() {
    from(...)
    .onException(...).log("This is Route level exception handling.");
    .to(...);
}
```

it will become a route level onException handler and it will be used only for exceptions on that single route.

Route level onException definitions will override RouteBuilder level definitions (e.g. if both define onException(MyException.class) then only the one defined directly in the route will be called if MyException is raised on that route).

**onCompletion** will behave the same way as onException.

About the "**try moving OnException to the top of route**" exception you are getting: you are supposed to only define onException at the beginning of the route like this:

```java
from(sftp:conf).OnException(Throwable.class).restExceptionconf
   .to(file:conf);
```

Further reading about onException [here](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) and about onCompletion [here](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html).

Comment: Hi jnupponen,Thanks for the prompt response. Gone through the documentation for both OnException and OnCompletion. At OnException documentation it is written that onException works per routeBuilder. I think you are saying in reverse order. Also I got the cause of getting exception ...move the OnCompletion to route level. I was using the choice() in my route and earlier i have not ended the choice() via end(), that is why I was getting the exception. Thanks for the help jnupponen.

Comment: Good catch!  I did edit the answer accordingly. I was confusing this with defining errorHandlers (it says in Camel In Action that: "Camel allows you to define a global context-coped error handler that’s used by default, and, if needed, you can also configure a route-scoped error handler that applies only for a particular route.")